# Net 4.5 compiled c++/cli dll is not running in windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, c++-cli

Recently I migrated projects from vs 2008 to vs 2013 and tried to deploy the binary in Windows server 2008 r2. I installed 2013 redistributable there.Most the exe is starting up but some are not.On analysis I found that those exe which uses c++/cli dll is not starting up.
Please help me on this.

Comment: There are no 32-64 bit problems, right? The Windows Server is 64 bits...

Comment: @xanatos No Its not 32-64 bit problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is a .NET 4.5 runtime actually installed on the Windows 2008 r2? It does not come with .NET 4.5 and the 2013 redistributable does not provide the .NET runtime, only the required unmanaged libraries for c++ are included in the redistributable.

You have to install a 4.5 runtime as well.

Comment: I found web installer only do we have exe installer ?